# Handlebarsjs - converting a object in to 3 columns not getting the result

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I have a object, which contains 15 data inside, i decide to place them in to 3 columns, i am using the helper function to split them as 3 group and finally returing a new object. after i return the object i am using the if conditions to manipulate the elements..

can any one advice me what i am doing wrong or show me the correct way to do it..?

here is the html part :

```
<div id="columns"></div>

 <script id="navi-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#colMaker this}}
            {{#if this.f}}
                <div class="col0">{{name}}</div>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if this.s}}
                <div class="col1">{{name}}</div>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if this.t}}
                <div class="col2">{{name}}</div>
            {{/if}}
        {{/colMaker}}
</script>
```

temp part of works:

```
var obj = {
    "columns":[ {"name":"name1"},{"name":"name2"},{"name":"name3"},{"name":"name4"},{"name":"name5"},{"name":"name6"},
        {"name":"name7"},{"name":"name8"},{"name":"name9"},{"name":"name10"},{"name":"name11"},{"name":"name12"},
        {"name":"name13"},{"name":"name14"},{"name":"name15"}
    ]
}



Handlebars.registerHelper("colMaker", function(arr, options, context){

    var fn = options.fn, ret = "";

    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(i % 3 == 0){
            ret += fn({"f":"f","name" : arr[i].name});
        }else if(i % 3 == 1){
            ret += fn({"s":"s","name" : arr[i].name});
        }else if(i % 3 == 2){
            ret += fn({"t":"t","name" : arr[i].name});
        }
    }

    return ret;

})

var temp = Handlebars.compile($("#navi-template").html());
$("#columns").html(temp(obj.columns));
```

the way i like to take a result to keep the elements part in html document, not in loops.
Thanks in advance.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fhUPL/3/)

Comment: What is the problem you are actually facing. You are converting arr to 3 columns correctly. I just changed the width of the column container.

Comment: I am getting each labels in separate divs, i unable to group them all in 3 columns.. with best practice. I am looking to put all datas nested within 3 columns. (keeping html's in template)